# why inserted video in powerpoint 2013 cant be showed in powerpoint 2007?

Tags: office-2013, powerpoint-2013

i created a powerpoint presentation by office 2013 and i inserted a video in format MP4 to it .but when i open it by powerpoint 2007 the video not be showed.
what is the problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question has nothing to do with programming, and should have been posted to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you place the video in the same folder where you created your 2007 powerpoint presentation.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because, when you insert a video into a PowerPoint 2013 or 2010 presentation, PowerPoint 2013 and 2010 now embed the video into the presentation. PowerPoint 2007 Service Pack 1 and earlier versions do not support playing embedded videos in a presentation.

Solution 1:
Use the PowerPoint Viewer

Solution 2:
Update PowerPoint 2007 to the 2007 Microsoft Office suite Service Pack 2

More details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982947/